# How do I know what my reach is?

Tags: dnd-5e, reach

I know about opportunity attacks, but what about reach? I don't know how to find out what my reach is.

Answer (score 20):

The answer can be found on page 195 of the PHB:

> Most creatures have a 5-foot reach and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger than Medium) have melee attacks with a greater reach than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions.

Aside from that, certain weapons also increase your reach if they have the **reach** property, as described on page 147 of the PHB:

> **Reach.** This weapon adds 5 feet to your reach when you attack with it.