# At what point in a creature's movement does an opportunity attack take place?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack

The specific situation is as follows:

My warlock with War Caster has a bonfire from Create Bonfire the tile in front of them, and a hostile creature in the bonfire. On my warlock's turn, I successfully affect the hostile creature with Dissonant Whispers, provoking an opportunity attack through movement, satisfying War Caster's requirement.

**Can I cast Lightning Lure, as my opportunity attack, once the creature has used 15 feet of movement, in order to attempt to proc damage from the creature leaving** (upon being forced to move by Dissonant Whispers) **and re-entering** (upon being pulled by Lightning Lure) **the tile with the bonfire?**

Or, must I take my opportunity attack immediately upon its trigger, while the creature is still effectively 5 feet away?

Comment: To be clear, War Caster doesn't let you cast spells as opportunity attacks; it lets you cast a spell instead of one. (It doesn't affect the answer to this question, though.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It must be taken immediately

When a reaction is taken, [it immediately follows the trigger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn) (**emphasis** mine):

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a special action called a reaction. A reaction is an **instant response to a trigger** of some kind

The trigger for the opportunity attack is...

> when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach

... so as soon as the creature leaves your reach (typically 5 feet), you must make the attack.

*Note: In general, reactions occur after their triggers, but opportunity attacks make an exception:*

> The attack occurs right before the creature leaves your reach.

Comment: Thank you for the swift and decisive response. But is the "reach" directly implying melee reach, or the reach of the spell which I am attempting to cast?

Comment: See here: [How do I know what my reach is?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101745/how-do-i-know-what-my-reach-is). Reach is irrespective of your activity (be it a spell or weapon attack). It is a property of the creature.

Comment: @MarkWells added

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your reach is 5ft, then your opportunity attack is executed before the creature leaves the fire tile. According to the PHB (pg 195):

> The [opportunity] attack interrupts the provoking creature's movement, **occurring right before the creature leaves your reach**.

Opportunity attacks are fundamentally about melee strikes, so the range is based on your melee range (ibid):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature ... moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you use your reaction to make one melee attack ...

If you have a class feature or similar that allows spells to be used for OAs, unless the text were to override the "reach" requirement explicitly, you would follow the general rule as above.